# WooCommerce PHP - If Product Category Has Children

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

In Woocommerce, I have product categories A, B, C & D. Categories B, C & D are all child categories of parent product category - A, like so:

> Product Category A
>
> - Child B
> - Child C
> - Child D

I need a simple PHP conditional statement / code that allows me to target and apply code to the child categories of parent category A only.

ie:

```
<?php 
  if (cat_is_ancestor_of(A, $cat) or is_category(A)):  ?>
  <div id="div>
  Do this
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This will not work, since "`cat_isancestor_of`" doesn't apply to Woocommerce product categories - Woocommerce uses the conditiatonal tag "`product_category`". For more info on Woocomerce condition statements see this: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/

I am fully aware of how to target child categories within Wordpress, but again not able to figure out how to do it within WooCommerce & product categories specifically. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, I was still not able to figure out how to apply that info to WooCommerce product categories though. If you could give a short example that would be great.

Comment: WooCommerce is off topic here - you'll need to ask at the WooCommerce forums. But that post should answer it as far as WP development goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all child category by using parent category id, I am using this code for access child  product category

```
$cat_id = 1; // A Category id 
$temp_terms = get_terms(array(
   'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'parent' => $cat_id,
    'order_by' => 'name',
));
```